# How can I call browser back or forward buttons using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible? And how can I call browser back function using jquery?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

why jquery? normal javascript support history.go(-1) or go(1)
or look at: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_forward.asp

Comment: one reason why a library such as jquery would be helpful is that not all browsers support history.go().   See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).  It claims that IE doesnt support this until version 10.

Comment: @dsjoerg thats for the html5 history api. `history.go` has been around for a while.

Comment: which one should I prefer, history.go(-1) or window.history.back() and why

Answer (score 17):

You don't need JQuery for this.

```
history.go(-1); // go back
history.go(1); // go forward
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need jquery for that:

- forward: `window.history.go(+1)`
- backward: `window.history.go(-1)`

Comment: Hi, how can I detect if page has forward page?
Ex: if(window.history.go() >= 1){ window.history.go(+1); }
I want that to hide forward button if do not needed.

Comment: You could check if `window.history.next` contains a url. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History

Answer (score 1):

JQuery makes sense to use when you want an unobtrusive way to display a browser back button. The following example will not display anything if javascript is disabled:

```
!function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ELEMENT').append('<div class="browser_back"><a class="browser_back_link" alt="go one page back" title="go one page back" href="#browser_back">back</a></div>');
    $('#ELEMENT .browser_back a').click(function() {
    window.history.go(-1);
    return false;
    });
}); }(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, you could also do:

`window.history.back()` to go back, or
`window.history.forward()` to go forward.